# Censoring letters in a string not working in a function

Tags: python, string, function, loops, for-loop

So I am currently learning about looping in strings, using "for".

I am trying to make a censoring function (sansur), which will turn all "m"s in a word into "*"s.

```
word = "Programming is fun!"


def sansur(hmm):
    for harf in hmm:
        if harf == "m":
            harf = "*"



deneme = sansur(word)
print deneme
```

If I do it like this, it just prints "none", but if I do it manually without a function like this, it works.

```
for harf in word:
    if harf == "m":
        harf = "*"

    print harf
```

I think my problem is because of the function.

Comment: It doesn't work because `harf` is simply a temporary local variable which is first assigned the value of each character in the string, and then immediately overwritten with `*` if its value is `m`. The original string is not modified in any way, nor do you produce a new string which you return.

Comment: thanks for the info! can you tell me how can I edit the original letters in the "word" variable by using the function?

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately, perhaps), you can't! You need to incrementally produce a new string by starting from an empty string in a local variable, and on each iteration replace it with its old value appended with the current character, or, if the current character is `m`, `*`. You can also do fancy things like comprehensions etc. but I would lay off those until you're rock solid on the fundamentals.

Comment: If you feel like peeking at the answer: http://ideone.com/sNxMLy

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def sansur(hmm):
    return hmm.replace('m','*')
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16879706)

Comment: @Torbjörn - it does, it may not be a very well written answer (and I don't know the subject well enough to know if it is a __correct__ answer), but it is still an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Python. That means you can not change it, but you have to create a new one!

So, you would have to rewrite it like this:

```
def process(msg):
    result = ""
    for ch in msg:
        if ch == "m":
            result += "*"
        else:
            result += ch
    return result
```

It inefficient, but close to your original. To test it:

```
>>> process("Programming is fun!")
'Progra**ing is fun!'
```

However, when you wish to "map" each element of a sequence to a new one, like we're doing above, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> word = "Programming is fun!"
>>> "".join(map(lambda c: "*" if c == "m" else c, word))
'Progra**ing is fun!'
```

Or, in a function:

```
def process(msg):
    return "".join(map(lambda c: "*" if c == "m" else c, msg))
```

But, for a simple character translation like this, it's much better to use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> word.replace("m", "*")
'Progra**ing is fun!'
```

Answer (score 0):

More in line with your original code:

```
word = "Programming is fun!"

def sansur(hmm):
    x = []
    for harf in hmm:
        if harf == "m":
            x.append("*")
        else:
            x.append(harf)
    return ''.join(x)


deneme = sansur(word)
print(deneme)
```

Basically, strings are immutable, so you aren't changing anything. Instead, I just appended the appropriate character to a new list based on your test, and then converted that list back to a string and returned it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your program is that you're not returning anything from that function.  Functions that complete without a return statement have a return value of `None`.

Even if you corrected that, it would not work.  The problem now is that you you're replacing the `for` variable, and not the actual position on the string.  When you do `for harf in hmm:`, harf becomes a copy of each  character on the string.  You then replace that copy, which gets lost on the next iteration.

You could change your implementation to put the `print` call right after the `if`:

```
def sansur(hmm):
    for harf in hmm:
        if harf == "m":
            harf = "*"
        print harf
```

However, as you're studying loops for strings, what you probably want is to aggregate the characters in a return variable, and then return it.

Here's a reimplementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

word = "Programming is fun!"

def sansur(hmm):
    ret = ""
    for harf in hmm:
        if harf == "m":
            ret += "*"
        else:
            ret += harf
    return ret

deneme = sansur(word)
print deneme
```

Which prints

Progra**ing is fun!

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is to use str.replace, like this:

```
def sansur(hmm):
    return hmm.replace('m','*')
```

Also, the reason that it prints 'None' with your function is because the function does not return anything. when you say

```
word='Programming is fun!'
print sansur(word)
```

you are printing the **value** of sansur(word), and a function's value is what it returns. Since your function returns nothing, it has no value; it will print 'None'.